# How to create ExpensiveGraph

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, caffeine

I want to use below code in my application

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(10_000)
    .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
```

But, I am so dumb in multithreading that I could not figure it out how do I implement the function createExpensiveGraph.
Please help.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-caching-caffeine) might help. It could simply be `return 42;`. The cache will invoke it atomically per-key, but it may be called concurrently across different keys. So any shared state (like an http client) has to be used in a threadsafe manner.

Comment: The tutorial link did help. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `createExpensiveGraph` is just a placeholder for whatever function you would like to cache. It could be to retrieve a value from a database, make a HTTP call, or compute a computationally expensive value. Depending on what you would like to cache, you have to implement - and name appropriately - this function yourself.